# Promise.all() based on functions returning Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to use `Promise.all()` with Promises encapsulated on functions:

```
function fn1(val){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  

       /* promise body */        
    });    
}


function fn2(val){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  

       /* promise body */        
    });    
}



fn1(data)
.then((val) => fn2(val))
.catch((error) => alert(error)



Promise.all([fn1, fn2]).then(() => alert("Done!"))
```

This seems not possible as the `Promise.all([fn1, fn2])` executes directly instead of waiting for the promises to success.

I know I could just chain another `.then()` to the *thenable* structure, but I wonder if there is any way of using `Promise.all()` on a context where Promises are contained into functions.

Comment: `Promise.all([fn1(val), fn2(val)]).then(() => alert("Done!"))`? Just call the functions when you define `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all` takes an `Array` of `Promise`s.

Since your functions return Promises you can *call* the functions while declaring the `Promise.all` Array and they will be *replaced* by the Promises.

```js
//  error handling (reject/catch) omitted for brevity.

function fn1 (val) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('foo ' + val)
  })
}

function fn2 (val) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve('bar ' + val)
  })
}

Promise.all([fn1(1), fn2(2)])
  .then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: Thank you. So there's no point on mixing a .then() structure with a Promise.all() ? As Promise.all() is for independent Promises with no dependence between

Comment: Not like you're doing in your example. `Promise.all` takes an array of **both** resolved or unresolved `Promises`, and waits for all of them to resolve.

Comment: Got it. Very Grateful Nik